# Removing multiple lines of code in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Throughout my solution I've got many occurrences of code that follow a specific pattern:

```
try
{
   ...
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    throw new CustomException(ex);
}
```

The pattern is always exactly the same except for the code inside the try.  I want to remove the surrounding try/catch and leave the inner code, anywhere this pattern occurs.  Is there some kind of search/replace I can use here?

Comment: You have to use a regular expression find/replace.

Comment: Do you have ReSharper? Its structural search-and-replace feature would be ideal for this.